# Expected expression before '||' token

Tags: c, error-handling, compiler-errors, conditional-statements

I'm in the process of learning C. I encounter an error message "Expected expression before || token".

```
#include <stdio.h>
char calculate_Easter_date(int y);

int main()
{
    int year;
    char sol [80];
    while (1)
    {
        scanf("%d", &year);
        if (year == EOF){
                break;
        }
        sol = calculate_Easter_date(year);
        printf("%s\n", sol);
    }
    return 0;
}

char calculate_Easter_date(int y)
{
    char buf[80];
    int g = (y % 19) + 1;
    int c = (y / 100) + 1;
    int x = (3 * c / 4) - 12;
    int z = ((8 * c + 5) / 25) - 5;
    int d = (5 * y / 4) - x - 10;
    int e = (11 * g + 20 + z - x) % 30;
    if ((e == 25) && (g > 11)) || (e == 24){
        e ++;
    }
    int n = 44 - e;
    if (n < 21){
        n += 30;
    }
    int n = (n + 7) - ((d + n) mod 7);
    if (n > 31){
        sprintf(buf, "%d APRIL %d", y, n - 31);
        return buf;
    }
    else{
        sprintf(buf, "%d MARCH %d", y, n);
        return buf;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have one too many end parentheses on the 8th line of calculate_Easter_date()

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
if (((e == 25) && (g > 11)) || (e == 24)) {
        e ++;
    }
```

Note the extra parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

In C and C++, if-statements are on this form:

```
if (expression) statement;
```

The statement can of course be a block, delimited by `{` and `}` but that's not what is wrong here.

Note that the expression to check must be enclosed in parenthesis.

So this line:

```
if ((e == 25) && (g > 11)) || (e == 24){
```

Is the culprit.

Let me highlight a portion of it

```
    +-------+    +------+
    |       |    |      |
    v       v    v      v
if ((e == 25) && (g > 11)) || (e == 24){
   ^                     ^
   |                     |
   +---------------------+
```

The lower highlight shows you where the parenthesis that delimit the expression is located, and this means that your if-statement is as follows:

```
if (expression) || (e == 24){
                ^
                +-- start of the statement
```

To fix this, you need to add another level of parenthesis to enclose the extra bits:

```
   +------------- add these ------------+
   |                                    |
   | +-------+    +------+              |
   | |       |    |      |              |
   v v       v    v      v              v
if (((e == 25) && (g > 11)) || (e == 24)){
    ^                     ^
    |                     |
    +---------------------+
```